# Applying multiple hash functions to improve security?

Tags: hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guarding against cryptanalytic breakthroughs: combining multiple hash functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/270/guarding-against-cryptanalytic-breakthroughs-combining-multiple-hash-functions)

I'm a total newb to cryptography but after reading what I've read about it, I had a simple idea and I wonder if it has any merit. What if you encrypted using a selection of hash algorithms applied sequentially instead of one, or multiple iterations of the same one? Which hash algorithms to apply and/or in what order could be chosen randomly and recorded in a salt which would be supplied along with any other salt. In fact it could increase complexity further by adding an additional random salt string in between each hash function. The authentication program would take the salt(s) and apply the same steps in the same order.

Like I said, I'm a complete beginner to crypto and maybe this is a crappy idea for one reason or another, or maybe it or something like it is already a known technique. At least naively it seems like it would be an easy way to make something tougher to crack.

Comment: Look at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/959/706 and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/270/706. They somewhat related to your question.

Comment: The question is ill-formulated. In particular, one does not _encrypt_ with a _hash_ function. However, the intuition is right: **yes**, security of cryptographic primitives can be improved by combining multiple ones, at the cost of performance and (sometime) size of hashes or/and keys (for algorithms with keys, which does not include hashes). In the case of hashes, this is discussed [here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~xb/crypto06b/blackboxhash.pdf) and [there](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/524.pdf). It also works for [MACs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) and encryption.

Comment: Multiple iterations of the same hash is often useful. However, `Ha(Hb(Hc(Hd(message))))` is only as strong as the weakest in the chain.

Comment: I've closed this for now as a duplicate of the other question, the discussion on there should help I hope :) If your question is different (and I'm just not seeing it), do feel free to edit/reply to me here and we can look at re-opening it.